# OpenGL data types for non-Graphics C/C++ code?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

Has anybody ever used the custom, "portable" data types defined in OpenGL (C API) header files for non-Graphics related C/C++ programs? (That is, to ensure their data types remained of the same size across compilers/platforms)

If anyone has, did you encounter any problems in doing so? Also, would you consider it a viable option for use in professional level (non Graphics related) C/C++ code (for the same reason)?

Comment: Why use those when you have `std::intX_t`/`std::uintX_t`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX standard introduces [stdint.h](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/basedefs/stdint.h.html) header that provides standard fixed width integer types.

C99 introduced the same header as a C language standard see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer). C++ provides those types as part of `std` namespace in [cstdint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint)

This covers integer types. Float types are slightly trickier since both C and C++ language standards provide no guarantees about exact precision and internal representation.

For instance, [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) makes just the following statements:

> (6.5.2) 10.There are three real floating types, designated as float, double, and long
> double.32) The set of values of the type float is a subset of the set of values of the type double; the set of values of the type double is a subset of the set of values of the type long double.

Usually, they are implemented as [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) 32bit/64bit floating numbers plus an odd 80bit for long double.

OpenGL on the other hand provides an exact guarantee of the [FP representation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Type).

> GLfloat   32  An IEEE-754 floating-point value    GL_FLOAT

However, in an implementation will see:

> typedef float     GLfloat;    /* single precision float */

This was taken from [MESA GL.h](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/blob/main/include/GL/gl.h)

Conclusion: Theoretically OpenGL provides the guarantee of the FP representation, in practice, this is offloaded to a compiler that implements the language that provides no such guarantees.

PS. Boost with a lot of `#ifdef` magic provides [cstdfloat](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/boost/cstdfloat.hpp) that defines fixed-width float types in `boost` namespace - see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/rationale.html

But dragging in boost as a dependency is a completely different topic for discussion =)